# About complexity of a language

Tags: formal-languages, computability

I have a language which is made out of and has a grammar only operating on well parenthesized words or words of one symbol. I want to know if the problem of belonging to this language is decidable.

**Example.** Consider the following grammar:
$$a \to a(aa) \\ a \to b \\a (a(a(ab))) \to b$$
I'll denote by $L(x)$ the language generated by the above grammar and rule $S \to x$.

Trivially, $b \in L(a)$, using rule 2.
Also $b \in L(a(aa))$ by the sequence of productions $a(aa) \to a(a(a(aa))) \to a(a(a(ab))) \to b$.
However $b \notin L(aa)$ because after applying rule 1 any number of times and then rule 2, symbol $a$ will be repeated $2n + 1$ times and rule 3 can only remove $4m$ of them.

Note, the grammar is actually dealing with trees. Parentheses denote a subtree and symbols denote leaves. Hopefully the notation is clear enough. The language seems much weaker than RE but stronger than context free.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you asking whether (a) the particular language in your example is decidable, or (b) any grammar which is like your example gives a decidable language?

Comment: And it looks decidable to me.

Comment: I'm asking generally about this type of grammars. The example language is a bit trivial.

Comment: Oh, in general it is going to be undecidable, I think. Let me think.

Comment: @AndrejBauer, would you elaborate on that?

Comment: Well, I would try to encode a Post correspondence problem or a semi-Thue system. These require manipulation of lists, which are special cases of binary trees. The only technicality is how to rewrite when the list is "nested" in the wrong order.

Comment: @AndrejBauer, what I have here is a very restricted semi-Thue system (I suppose I should have named it as such, rather than a grammar). If I have a word $a(b(c(\dots)))$ then my rules can only operate on its end. If I have $(\dots)(\dots)\dots$ then my rules can only operate on one $(\dots)$ at a time (or the root).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I completely removed the previous answer, which was applicable only to this particular example).

Your grammars seem to be known as *ground term rewriting systems* nowadays.

They are rather old. They might be introduced by W.S. Brainard: Tree generating regular systems. Inform. and Control 14 (1969) 217-231.

Concerning your question. I googled a paper of a good old collegue. Joost Engelfriet: Derivation trees of ground term rewriting systems. If my hunch, that this is the correct model, is correct, I like to cite Theorem 4 of that paper:

> For every extended ground tree grammar $G$ a regular tree grammar $G'$ with $L(G') = L(G)$ can effectively be constructed.

It is in the section called "New proofs for old results", so that must be a known result.

Comment: Hope it helps! The author JE is always adding full references, so perhaps there are other probably other points to start (less technical?). And, if the model is the one you are looking for, you know now what to google  :)